# _this2.setState is not a function on react asynchonous

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I have some function (Promise Resolve) when onChange handler
This function will fetch data array by `PromiseValue`, so I use `.Then( result )` to get the array field and it work when I print `result` with console.log.
But the problem is on `this.setState` because always get error with error message : **_this2.setState is not a function**

```
getList(checkboxes['myCheckbox']).then(
    result =>   {
      this.setState({ CheckBox: result })           
    }
).catch( err =>  {
    console.log(err)
});
```

thanks before

Comment: can you publish code of component?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x37p5kgb/

Answer (score 0):

Without more of the component, I'd guess this is probably occurring because your `onChange` handler in your component isn't bound to the `class` instance. So when the `onChange` fires and the promise code is executed, `this.setState` will not be defined.

You could make it work if you:

- bound the functions in the constructor of the class component, i.e. `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)`
- use the class fields syntax, i.e. `const handleChange = () => { // your code };`
- converted the component to a functional component and used hooks, i.e. `useState`;

I could be wrong though as I don't have the full text of the code! Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have trying this before, but still failed
https://jsfiddle.net/x37p5kgb/

Answer (score 0):

Inside Promise.then(). **this** always refers to the callback function itself. so there would be no **setState** function.

Try defining a new function to save the result into the state.

Comment: I understand about that, but currently I need to set some state for some reason.

Comment: Thats ok.. you can create a function, which takes the result as input and calls the setState. And you can call this function inside your Promise.then()